# Best way to combine mysql and Facebook sign up/in

Tags: swift, facebook

There are two ways how to sign up to my iOS app. First option is using `mysql/php` (user types email,username,password and I store that in mysql database.
Second option is log in using Facebook and here starts my problem , because I need to have userId, which I can get from Facebook, but I also have an Id in my MySQL database(every user should have his own Id).
So my question is what would you recommend me to do. I have tried to store Facebook user to mysql so he received his unique Id.(but then there were empty columns like password, because Facebook user does not need password).

This is my Facebook sign in (when I sign in with my Facebook account it is ok because my Facebook id Is a pretty high number):

```
@IBAction func btnFBLoginPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

   loadingIndicator.startAnimating()

    FBSDKLoginManager().logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email"],
                                                 fromViewController:self,
        handler: { (result:FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

            if (error == nil){

                self.getFBUserData()

                self.loadingIndicator.stopAnimating()
            }else{

                self.loadingIndicator.stopAnimating()
                let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert!", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .Alert)
                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil)
                myAlert.addAction(okAction)
                self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                print(error.localizedDescription)
                print("error")
                return
            }

    })
}

func getFBUserData(){
    if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                print(result)

                 print(result["name"])
                 print(result["id"])
                                 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(result["name"]!, forKey: "username")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(result["id"]!, forKey: "userId")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

                let firstPage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController")as! ViewController
                let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate
                appDelegate?.window??.rootViewController = firstPage                                                                           

}else{

                let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert!", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .Alert)
                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil)
                myAlert.addAction(okAction)
                self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                print(error.localizedDescription)
                print("error")
                return


            }
        })
    }
}
```

This is MySQL sign in:

```
 @IBAction func loginTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

let userEmail = emailTextField.text
let userPassword = passwordTextField.text



    if (userEmail!.isEmpty||userPassword!.isEmpty){

        let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "All fields must be filled out", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        myAlert.addAction(okAction)
        self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }
       self.loadingIndicator.startAnimating()

   let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://localhost/~myPc/userSignIn.php")!
   let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl)
   request.HTTPMethod = "POST"


    let postString = "userEmail=\(userEmail!)&userPassword=\(userPassword!)"

    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)


    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) in

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){

            if (error != nil){

                let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .Alert)
                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil)
                myAlert.addAction(okAction)
                self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                self.loadingIndicator.stopAnimating()

                return
            }

            do {
                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                if let parseJson = json {

                    let userId = parseJson["userId"] as? String
                      if userId != nil{


                        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(parseJson["username"], forKey: "username")

                        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(parseJson["userId"], forKey: "userId")
                        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()


                     let firstPage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController")as! ViewController
                     let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate

                     appDelegate?.window??.rootViewController = firstPage

                    }else{
                        let userMessage = parseJson["message"] as? String
                        let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: .Alert)
                        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil)
                        myAlert.addAction(okAction)
                        self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                        self.loadingIndicator.stopAnimating()

                    }

                    self.loadingIndicator.stopAnimating()

                }

            } catch {
                print(error)

            }           
        }
    }).resume()

    }
```